# Editar cadena de caracteres en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando en Python, tengo el siguiente string:

```
mensaje="Esta es la linea uno\nEsta es la linea dos\nEsta es la linea tres"
```

y quiero imprimir el siguiente mensaje:

```
linea 1:Esta(1) es(2) la(3) linea(4) uno(5)
linea 2:Esta(1) es(2) la(3) linea(4) dos(5)
linea 3:Esta(1) es(2) la(3) linea(4) tres(5)
```

como puedo hacer para agregar texto en medio de la cadena pero sin reemplazar nada?

Comment: Hola Agustín, ¿Es una pregunta genérica?¿o lo que buscas es insertar el par de paréntesis después de cada palabra con el numero de ésta dentro? Realmente una cadena no puede modificarse, es inmutable. Ya sea reemplazar o insertar requiere crear una nueva cadena siempre, tendrás que partir la cadena y luego concatenar o usar formato de cadenas para construir la nueva.

Comment: si lo que quiero es ya se generar una nueva cadena de texto usando los datos de la primera o editar la original, pero por lo visto tendre que crear una nueva

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar lo que quieres puedes usar la función `split`

```
mensaje = "Esta es la linea uno\nEsta es la linea dos\nEsta es la linea tres"
line_number = 1
for line in mensaje.split('\n'): # dividimos el string en lineas dentro de una lista
    word_number = 1
    line_text = f'linea {line_number}: ' # indicamos la linea
    for word in line.split():  # dividimos las palabras
        line_text = f'{line_text} {word}({word_number})' # agregamos cada palabra y su número a la linea
        word_number += 1
    print(line_text)
    line_number += 1
```

El resultado:

linea 1:  Esta(1) es(2) la(3) linea(4) uno(5)
linea 2:  Esta(1) es(2) la(3) linea(4) dos(5)
linea 3:  Esta(1) es(2) la(3) linea(4) tres(5)

Que es exactamente lo que deseas

Comment: Muchisimas gracias

Comment: @AgustinCoronel si te solucionó el problema, es buena práctica aceptar la respuesta. Más info en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Sería esto:

```
mensaje="Esta es la linea uno\nEsta es la linea dos\nEsta es la linea tres"
lineas = mensaje.split("\n")
count = 0
for linea in lineas:
    linea_lst = linea.split(" ")
    linea = ""
    for palabra in linea_lst:
        count += 1
        linea = linea + palabra + "(" + str(count) + ") "
    linea = "linea " + str(count) + ": " + linea + "\n"
    count = 0
    print(linea)
```

Answer (score 0):

Una propuesta diferente, usando list-comprehension:

```
def numeraPalabras(linea):
  palabras = [f'{palabra}({i+1})' for i, palabra in enumerate(linea.split(' '))]
  return ' '.join(palabras)

mensaje="Esta es la linea uno\nEsta es la linea dos\nEsta es la linea tres"

palabrasNumeradas = [numeraPalabras(linea) for linea in mensaje.split('\n')]
lineasNumeradas = [f'Linea {i+1}: {linea}' for i, linea in enumerate(palabrasNumeradas)]

for linea in lineasNumeradas:
  print(linea)
```

Puebes probarlo aquí: https://repl.it/repls/NanoAggravatingChief